# Reading back Linux gre[tap] local/remote address

Tags: linux, linux-networking, iproute2, gre

With iproute2 on Linux, gre/gretap interfaces are setup with `ip link add`, which for GRE needs `remote` and optionally `local` attributes specifying the endpoints. However, I can't find any way to *read back* these attributes. `ip link show` doesn't show them, and they don't seem to be represented anywhere in the data structures returned by the C function `getifaddrs` (e.g. if I wanted to implement my own tool to get them). I'm working with an environment where there are a very large number of such interfaces, and I need to be able to find the one associated with a particular remote address. Is there any way to do that without storing the mapping somewhere out-of-band?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get all information from an interface, you can use [`ip`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip.8)'s `-details` option:

> `-d`, `-details`
>
> Output more detailed information.

```
# ip link add name gretaptest type gretap remote 192.0.2.1 local 192.0.2.2
# ip -details link show dev gretaptest
49: gretaptest@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1462 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5e:1d:10:f9:05:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 minmtu 68 maxmtu 0 
    gretap remote 192.0.2.1 local 192.0.2.2 ttl inherit erspan_ver 0 addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535
```

If you want to use this in scripts, you really should use `-json` along the [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) tool. Very basic example (without any check):

```
# ip -json -details link show dev gretaptest | jq '.[].linkinfo.info_data | .remote, .local'
"192.0.2.1"
"192.0.2.2"
```

If you want to implement this directly in your tools using available system calls and functions, you should start by taking a look there:

- [`rtnetlink (7)`](https://manpages.debian.org/rtnetlink.7)          - Linux IPv4 routing socket (it's a lot more than just IPv4)

  for interfaces it's probably RTM_GETLINK
- [`rtnetlink (3)`](https://manpages.debian.org/rtnetlink.3)          - macros to manipulate rtnetlink messages

You can run `strace` on the `ip`command to just see the kind of system calls and structures in use.

Some documentation found around:

[networking:generic_netlink_howto](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/generic_netlink_howto)

There are higher libraries built on top of this such as [libnl](https://www.infradead.org/%7Etgr/libnl/) too.

Comment: also added a few links for a direct implementation (it doesn't look easy considering all the glue code)

Comment: Also for multiple interfaces, if sticking to json, have a look at a very similar answer of mine on UL SE where there are better json examples: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616157/iproute2-how-to-display-the-type-of-a-network-devices/616162#616162

Comment: Thanks - this is perfect!